# C# .NET listing contents of remote files

Tags: .net

Is it possible in .NET to list files on a remote location like an URL? Much in the same way the System.IO classes work. All I need is the URLs to images that are on a remote server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, unless you have more control over that web-server

**Long answer:** Here are possible solutions...

1. You will need server-side script that will do it locally and output this list in your preferred format.
2. Most of the web-servers implement default file-browsing pages, so you could theoretically parse those but this solution will be very fragile and not very portable even between different versions of the same web-server.
3. If you have FTP access...

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible in .NET to list files on a remote location like an URL?

You should specify which protocol we're talking about.

For HTTP, lubos hasko provided the answer: no. HTTP has no concept of files; only of resources. If you have control over the web server, you can ask it to provide a directory listing, or, better yet, you can write code that lists the directory server-side for you. Without such control, you have to *rely* on the server to provide a listing, which 1) may be disabled for security reasons, 2) is non-standardized in its format, 3) will be, like lubos said, fragile to parse (["scrape"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)).

If you mean / if the server provides a protocol intended for file transfer, such as FTP, SMB/CIFS, etc., it'll be a lot easier. For example, for FTP, you'll want to look into [WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.listdirectorydetails.aspx).